# Create a bidirectional ManyToOne relation

Tags: data-modeling, playframework, cascade, many-to-one

Hi I try to create a ManyToOne relation but get stucked.

I have a BILL and a Booking Class

The realation is :
A Bill can have many Bookings. (1:m)
The Bill Class should manage the relationship
A Booking belong only to one Bill. (1:1 A Booking can't exist without a Bill )

If I delete the Bill, all Bookings that belongs to the Bill should be deleted.
If I remove a Booking from the Bill, only this Booking should be deleted.
If I delete a Booking, this Booking should be removed from the Bill.

So far i have this model :

Bill Class

```
@Entity

public class Bill extends Model{


@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})

public List<Booking> bookings;


public void setBookings(List<Booking> bookings)

{

       for (Booking booking : bookings) 
       {
        booking.bill = this;
       }
}

}
```

Booking Class

```
@Entity
public class Booking extends Model{

@ManyToOne(optional=false )

@Required(message="Bill needed")

public Bill bill;


public void setBill(Bill bill){

        this.bill=bill;

        bill.bookings.add(this);

    }
}
```

If I delete the `Bill`, all Bookings belong to the `Bill` deleted as well.
But I can't delete a single `Booking`, either from the `Bill` Side or the `Booking` side.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

Your case is the standard parent child case. You need to declare the following:

```
@Entity
public class Bill extends Model {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="bill")
    public List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
}

@Entity
public class Booking extends Model {
    @ManyToOne public Bill bill;
}
```

This code contains all necessary declarations. The orphanRemoval ensures that whenever you delete a Booking from Bill (i.e., when that Booking becomes orphaned) it will be deleted from the database. If you delete the Bill, then all its BookingS are deleted as well (via the CascadeType.ALL annotation).

With the above declarations, you can set Bookings by

```
for(Booking booking : bookings) {
    bill.bookings.add(booking);
    booking.bill = bill;
}
```

(you don't need to code setBookings() yourself) but you must make sure that you do the change on both sides.

For removal, if you set a Booking's bill to null and remove the booking from the Bill's bookings:

```
booking.bill = null;
bill.bookings.remove(booking);
```

should do it.

If you call

```
booking.delete();
```

then also its bookings should be deleted.

Really quite standard....

Comment: Thx for the answer, but if i use the mappedBy="bill" than the Bookings will handle the realation between this classes. How can I change it, so the relation will be handled by Bill Class.

Comment: The Booking table get's the foreign key, yes. What else do you mean with "handles the relation"?

Comment: That the Bill class handle the foreign key

Comment: The foreign key can only be mapped to the many side of the relation, or to an extra mapping table.

Comment: That means, i have to use a JoinTable(bill_id) on both sides and create my own seter for this ?